# How to filter out the where clause in a query builder?

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I'm building an dynamic application with a query builder that consists of four select lists where the user can enter the table, column, operator and attribute names. Now I also want the user to be able to do select ALL. So the user should have the option to only select the table, and column name(=ALL). But I don't know how to filter out the where clause then. This is my php script at the moment:

```
<?php

include "connect.php";

$table          = $_GET['tableSelected'];
$field          = $_GET['fieldSelected'];
$attribute      = $_GET['attributeSelected'];
$operator       = $_GET['operatorSelected'];
$tableList      = $_GET['tableList'];
$fieldList      = $_GET['fieldList'];
$attributeList  = $_GET['attributeList'];

$fieldstr = $fieldList . ",ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(l.geom,4326))";


$sql = "SELECT $fieldstr
        FROM $table l
        WHERE $field $operator '{$attribute}'";

if (!$response = pg_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "A query error occured.\n";
    exit;
}

while ($row = pg_fetch_row($response)) {
    foreach ($row as $i => $attr){
        echo $attr.", ";
    }
    echo ";";
}

?>
```

Comment: Build the query string dynamically and only add the `WHERE` condition when the 3 needed fields are not empty. By the way, you should replace the value with a placeholder and use white-lists for the database-, table and column names to avoid sql injection / breaking your query.

Comment: Yeah that was the idea. But how to do that @jeroen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build your string dynamically and only add a `WHERE` condition if the required fields for that section are not empty.

For example:

```
$sql = "SELECT {$fieldstr}
        FROM {$table}";

if (!empty($field) && !empty($operator) && !empty($attribute)) {
    $sql .= " WHERE {$field} {$operator} '{$attribute}'";
}
```

By the way, you should replace the value with a placeholder and use white-lists for the database-, table and column names and the operators to avoid sql injection / breaking your query.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I will work on this. Yeah I will look into the placeholders. But you mean use placeholders in the index.html file? Or also in my php file?

Comment: @L.fcg I am not that familiar with the `pg_*` functions, but you should look for prepared statements.

Comment: I want to use placeholders for the value's but the problem is that my select lists are depended. So when the user selects a table name, the column and attribute select lists get filled in automatically.

Comment: could you maybe help me out with another question? This is the link to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37807123/how-to-create-an-and-button-that-adds-a-and-statement-to-a-query